# appscript form.data[x] increment

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

=== Answer added in code ===
please could you help me resolve this :
How get **form.test[j]** work in the Apps Script code of the form submit.
Input name are : test1 test2 test3 ....

**information :**

```
with <?= r[0] ?> = num 1 to 40
```

**2.html code of modal (working) :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad">
</script>
<script>

  function submitForm() {
google.script.run.appendRowFromFormSubmit(document.getElementById("formulaire"));
    document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("thanks").style.display = "block";
  }
    
</script>
<style>
body {
        padding: 0 0.5rem; /* à remplacer par "margin: 0;" si affiché dans une boîte de dialogue */
        color: #333;
        font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
        overflow: scroll;
      }
      p {
        margin: 0.8rem 0 0.3rem;
      }
      .annuler {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 1rem;
        font-size: 0.88rem;
        color: #888;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .annuler:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
      input[type="text"] {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        padding: 0.6rem 0.7rem;
        background: #f3f3f3;
        color: #444;
        border: none;
        font-size: 1.08rem;
        border-radius: 0.4rem;
      }
      input[type="button"] {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0.7rem 0 0.6rem;
        border: none;
        background: #30a392;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 1.15rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 0.4rem;
      }
      input[type="button"]:hover {
        background: #40ad96;
      }
      input[type="radio"]:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      #finbouton
      {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 50px;//800px;
      }
      p{
        background-color: #D3D3D3;
      }
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="form"><form id="formulaire">
      <input type="button" id="form" name="form" value="Enregistrer" onclick="submitForm();">
      </div>
      <table>
      <? htmlOrders().forEach(r => {?>
          <tr> 
          <td><input type="checkbox" id="test<?= r[0] ?>" name="test<?= r[0] ?>" value="checked" <?= r[1] ?> ></td>
          <td><?= r[2] ?></td>
          </tr>
      <?})?>
      </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="thanks" style="display: none;"><br><b>Attendre la fin de l'enregistrement.</b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**here app script code (form.test[j] not working)**

```
function appendRowFromFormSubmit(form) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Valeurs');
  

  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var nbrows = sheet2.getRange("F1").getValue();

  for(var j = 1; j <= nbrows; j = j+1){
    if (form["test" + j] != "1"){       // === Answer here ===
      var rowdata = "";
    }
    else{
      var rowdata = "checked";
    }

    var data1 = sheet2.getRange("H" + j).getValue(); 
    if (data1 != rowdata) {
      sheet2.getRange("I"+ j).setValue(email);
      sheet2.getRange("H"+ j).setValue(rowdata);
    }    
  };
}
```

Thanks for your help

---

**As requested, here the secondary app script code**

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('=> Menu ZCS <=')
    .addItem('Suivi', 'suivi')
    .addToUi();
}
function suivi() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('2')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('Suivi ZCS')      ;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
function htmlOrders() {
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = active.getSheetByName("Valeurs");
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("G1:K40"); 
  return data = myRange.getValues();
}
```

Objective is to valid step by step a tutorial. And update checkbox statut on H:H

**Table : sheet name : "Valeurs"**

| F | G | H | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| =COUNTIF(G:G;"<>") | 1 | checked | email | r1 | t1 |
|  | 2 |  |  | r2 | t2 |
|  | 3 | checked | email | r3 | t3 |
|  | 4 |  |  | r4 | t4 |
|  | 5 |  |  | r5 | t5 |
|  | 6 |  |  | r6 | t6 |

Comment: Did you evaluate your html template prior to rendering?

Comment: I dunno what you try to explain to me. Then i think no. how and where do that ? Thx

Comment: Your html contains scriplets so it is a [template](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates).  Templates need to be evaluated prior to rendering.

Comment: here is the function to open template ```function suivi() {
    var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('2')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('Suivi ZCS')      ;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}```

Comment: please post the code into your question

Comment: Can you also post  a complete example so that we can reproduce the problem as described by [mcve]

Comment: @Cooper Code added to question with a link to a test sheet with all the code. Thanks

Comment: Your html is incomplete.  there is no html,body,head,doctype

Comment: @Cooper full html code added and a table exemple too. Thanks

Comment: Your table does not seem to be correctly formatted

Comment: Table displayed perfectly in edit draft, but not here. If someone can edit post plz.

Comment: @Cooper i think table now display better. Thanks

Comment: @Cooper  "form.test1;" work.<br>But not a submit like "form.test[i];" If some one know how get this work in the function appendRowFromFormSubmit(form)

Comment: anyone please ?

Comment: Still missing the html template

Comment: All my code is in the question. What is html template ?

Comment: What is 2.html?

Comment: Question updated with more title on bloc of code

Comment: please look at code bloc named : "2.html code of modal (working) :"

Comment: Your script should be either in the head or the body

Comment: Your style tags are in the wrong place

Comment: Dioes the sidebar appear when you launch it?

Comment: i have only one problem, is get input value. I dont know how write form.test[j] because input incoming are test1 test2 test3. Maybe form.test+j or maybe form.test.j or maybe form.test(j) .

Comment: You should be able to look at the form in the console of the browser using colsole.log and see what the names are

Comment: name are "test1" , the number "1" change for each row and go from 1 to 40. So in code i would like to make a loop

Comment: What's keeping you from making loop?

Comment: form.test[j] not work / form.test1 work good.

Comment: for(var j = 1; j <= 40; j = j+1){

Comment: Try form[`\`test${j}\``]  or `form["test" + j]` The form is an object

Comment: how put your post as answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `form['test${j}']` or `form["test" + j]` The form is an object

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).